# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and multilabel-indicator targets. 'm getting this error :

Tags: python

Iam Getting this error: ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and multilabel-indicator targets. 'm getting this error : please help me.

input_path = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/chest_xray/'
def process_data(img_dims, batch_size):
test_set = []
test_labels = []

```
for cond in ['/NORMAL/', '/PNEUMONIA/']:
    for img in (os.listdir(input_path + 'test' + cond)):
        img = plt.imread(input_path+'test'+cond+img)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
        img = np.dstack([img, img, img])
        img = img.astype('float32') / 255
        if cond=='/NORMAL/':
            label = 0
        elif cond=='/PNEUMONIA/':
            label = 1
        test_set.append(img)
        test_labels.append(label)
    
test_set = np.array(test_set)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

return  test_set, test_labels
```